# Cannot add-assign within `Vec` of user-defined type

Tags: rust

Consider this code ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff4a0a18d3e322ae3d4d2db380829595)):

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct X(i32);

impl std::ops::AddAssign for X {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: Self) {
        self.0 += rhs.0;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut ary_i32 = [1_i32; 2];
    ary_i32[0] += ary_i32[1]; // OK

    let mut ary_x = [X(1); 2];
    ary_x[0] += ary_x[1]; // OK

    let mut vec_i32 = vec![1_i32; 2];
    vec_i32[0] += vec_i32[1]; // OK

    let mut vec_x = vec![X(1); 2];
    vec_x[0] += vec_x[1]; // error[E0502]: cannot borrow `vec_x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
}
```

Why I get E0502 only on `vec_x` line?
I could not understand why only the operations for `ary_x` and `vec_i32` are permitted. Does borrow checker treat builtin types (`i32`, `array`) specially?

Comment: I can't answer the question why it works for `i32`, but you can work around this by assigning `vec_vec_x[1][1]` to an intermediary variable `x` and `vec_vec_x[0][0] += x;` works because `X` implements `Copy`. You'll be adding a copied `X` instead of a reference. Intuitively this should be happening all along like it does for the `i32` version.

Comment: Arrays and slices are special to `[]` -- they don't use `Index`(`Mut`). Integers are special to `+=` because they don't use `AddAssign`. Apparently either flavor of specialness is enough in this case. `let slice_x: &mut [X] = &mut vec_x; slice_x[0] += slice_x[1];` also works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I researched some resources and read MIR of my code, and managed to understand what is going on.
The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200596/cannot-add-assign-within-vec-of-user-defined-type#comment118786403_67200596) by @trentcl will be the best answer.
I write the details as possible.

For `array`, `Index` and `IndexMut` traits are not used and compiler directly manipulates array elements (you can see this with MIR). So, borrowing problem does not exist here.

Explanating for `Vec`, [rustc guide](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/) is useful.
First, [Two-phase borrow](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/borrow_check/two_phase_borrows.html) is not applied to `vec_foo[0] += vec_foo[1]` statement.
And, the difference between `i32` and `X` is caused by [operator lowering](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/construction.html#operator-lowering).
Basically, statements like `vec_user_defined[0] += vec_user_defined[1]` are converted to function calls like `add_assign(index_mut(...), *index(...))`, and function arguments are evaluated from left to right. So, `index_mut()` borrows `x` mutably and `index()` tries to borrow `x`, and fails.
But for builtin types like `i32`, compound assignment operator is not converted to function call, and rhs is evaluated before lhs (you can see `index()` is called before `index_mut()` with MIR). So, for builtin types, `vec_builtin[0] += vec_builtin[1]` works.

I know these things from [lo48576's article](https://blog.cardina1.red/2019/07/29/borrowck-and-builtin-compound-assign/) (Japanese).

I considered some workarounds:

- Just use an intermediate variable as @sebpuetz [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200596/cannot-add-assign-within-vec-of-user-defined-type#comment118782780_67200596).
- Convert `Vec` to `slice` as @trentcl [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200596/cannot-add-assign-within-vec-of-user-defined-type#comment118786403_67200596). But this doesn't work well for multidimensional `Vec`.
- Write some macro to automatically introduce an intermediate variable. I found [rhs_first_assign](https://crates.io/crates/rhs_first_assign) crate does such works.

Answer (score 1):

Rust arrays live on the stack, are predictably sized, and therefore have stronger borrow checker guarantees. Vectors are smart pointers on the stack pointing at data that can grow and shrink on the Heap. Because the final example uses the Vector type, the borrow checker considers the entire Vector as a single mutably borrowed object when loading it from the Heap.

As you've observed, the borrow checker can create a mutable reference to a single element to something living on the Stack, whereas it creates a mutable reference to the Vector's smart pointer on the Stack, and then a further mutable reference to the data on the heap. This is why the immutable reference to `vec_vec_x[1][1]` fails.

As @sebpuetz noted in a comment, you can solve this by first copying an immutable reference to `vec_vec_x[1][1]`, then creating an immutable reference.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand why `ary_ary_x` works and `vec_vec_x` fails.
But then, why `vec_vec_i32` also works?

Comment: You're copying a *value* in my comment, not creating a immutable *reference*. I don't think this answers your question as it leaves open why `vec_vec_i32` is working. Additionally, this is the first time that I hear about the borrow checker treating `Vec` and arrays differently. Do you have a source for that? The difference between the array and `Vec` version should be due to Arrays being `Copy`able, you can verify this by changing the inner Arrays to `Vec<X>` in the array example, it won't compile anymore.

Comment: I tried `[Vec<T>; 2]` and `Vec<[T; 2]>`, and verified that `[Vec<X>; 2]` and `Vec<[X; 2]>` fails ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e18e962cd37d2b55a8544fb53e844ad0)).
Any type with element type `i32` works.

Comment: And, I also tried user-defined copyable container `Pair` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9050f136d113f6c80924fa95bf77ad78)). Then, `Pair<i32>` works but `Pair<X>` fails.
So, I think copyability is not the absolute reason why `array` works.